# Select a character if some character from a list is before the character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
/([a-záäéěíýóôöúüůĺľŕřčšťžňď])-$\s*/gmi
```

This regex selects **č-** from my text:

```
sme! a Želiezovce 2015: Spoloíč-
ne pre Európu. Oslávili aj 940.
```

But I want to select only `-` (without `č`) (if some character from the list `[a-záäéěíýóôöúüůĺľŕřčšťžňď]` is before the `-`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other languages you would use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
/(?<=[a-záäéěíýóôöúüůĺľŕřčšťžňď])-$\s*/gmi
```

This matches `-$\s*` only if it's preceded by one of the characters in the list.

However, Javascript doesn't have lookbehind, so the workaround is to use a capturing group for the part of the regular expression after it.

```
var match = /[a-záäéěíýóôöúüůĺľŕřčšťžňď](-$\s*)/gmi.match(string);
```

When you use this, `match[1]` will contain the part of the string beginning with the hyphen.

Comment: JS doesn't have lookbehinds.

Comment: @Oriol I thought it just didn't have negative lookbehind, I guess I misremembered.

Answer (score 0):

First, in regex everything you put in parenthesis will be broken down in the matching process, so that the matches array will contain the full matching string at it's `0` position, followed by all of the regex's parenthesis from left to right.

`/[a-záäéěíýóôöúüůĺľŕřčšťžňď](-)$\s*/gmi`

Would have returned the following matches for you string: `["č-", "-"]` so you can extract the specific data you need from your match.

Also, the `$` character indicates in regex the end of the line and you are using the multiline flag, so technically this part `\s*` is just being ignored as nothing can appear in a line after the end of it.

The correct regex should be `/[a-záäéěíýóôöúüůĺľŕřčšťžňď](-)$/gmi`